# OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: when trying plt.savefig

Tags: python, matplotlib

I had come across an error, and I didn't quite know what the problem is and why I'm getting this error. In my script, I have users input a text file, and create a datatable from that text file. I extract and save one of the columns of the datatable individually (I have "bolded" the input that's causing the error to make it easier).

```
**File_Names=[]**
print('Enter name of peaklist files. When finished, type done and enter to stop.')
while True:
        Titration_file_input = input()
        if Titration_file_input.lower() not in ['done']:
                Titration_files.append(Titration_file_input)
        else:
            break

for Data in Titration_files:
    try:
        Titration_Datatable = pd.read_csv(Data, sep='\s+', header=None)
        Titration_Datatable.columns=['Column_1','Column_2','Column_3', 'Column_4', 'Column_5']
        Data_Table.append(Titration_Datatable)
    except:
        print('File' + ' ' + Data + ' ' + 'not found')


for Titration_Datatable in Data_Table:
    Peak_Height.append(Titration_Datatable.loc[:,'Column_4'])
    **File_Names.append(Titration_Datatable.loc[:,'Column_1'].drop([0],axis=0).drop([1],axis=0))**
```

I am then later calling it to use as the title of the savefiles for the graphs generated.

```
for values,i in zip(Titration_Data,File_Names):
    Intensity=[values]
    Intensity_Array=np.array(Intensity)
    y=Intensity_Array.flatten()
    popt, pcov = curve_fit(fun, x, y)
    kD.append(popt)
    fun_data=fun(x,*popt)
    output_for_graphing.append(fun_data)
    residuals=y-fun(x, popt)
    ss_res=np.sum(residuals**2)
    ss_tot=np.sum((y-np.mean(y))**2)
    r_squared=1-(ss_res/ss_tot)
    r2.append(r_squared)
    std = np.sqrt(np.diag(pcov))
    standard_deviation.append(std)
    plt.plot(x, y, label='data')
    plt.plot(x, fun(x, *popt), label='fitted')
    plt.xlabel('Ligand Concentration')
    plt.ylabel('Intensity')
    plt.title([i])
    plt.grid()
    plt.legend()
    **files_to_save=str([i])+'.png'
    plt.savefig(files_to_save)**
    plt.show()
```

The error I get is this:

```
  plt.savefig(files_to_save)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: '[2    1XH-HN\n3    2XH-HN\n4    3XN-HN\n5    4XN-HN\n6    5XN-HN\n7    6XN-HN\n8    7XN-HN\n9    8XN-HN\nName: Column_1, dtype: object].png'
```

I thought maybe its a formatting issue, maybe if I make it into a list or array it'll work. But when I changed it to an array, this is the error I get:

```
  plt.savefig(files_to_save)
OSError: [Errno 22] Invalid argument: "[array(['1XH-HN', '2XH-HN', '3XN-HN', '4XN-HN', '5XN-HN', '6XN-HN',\n       '7XN-HN', '8XN-HN'], dtype=object)].png"
```

At this point, I don't know why I'm getting the formatting error. The only thing I could think of is that plt.savefig doesn't accept hyphens, or is it that it can't read them (e.g. simply need to define what encoding is being used)? Thank you ahead of time!

Comment: What did you expect `files_to_save` to be exactly?

Comment: The name of the file that is being saved

Comment: And that would be...? (Please show an example)

Comment: e.g. the first file would be called 1XH-HN.png

Comment: Seems like you need to do fewer things at once and do some debugging on your own. See https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/

Answer (score 2):

You're trying to save **one** file called

> [2    1XH-HN\n3    2XH-HN\n4    3XN-HN\n5    4XN-HN\n6    5XN-HN\n7    6XN-HN\n8   7XN-HN\n9    8XN-HN\nName: Column_1, dtype: object].png

You can't save a file with brackets, backslashes, and colons. `str[i]` returns a list of filenames and that's where you went wrong. Maybe try

```
for ix, (values,i) in enumerate(zip(Titration_Data,File_Names)):
    # etc
```

Then you'll be able to index with a number `str[ix]`. I think you were using `zip` wrong. Here's a simple example of how it works:

```
a = [1, 2, 3, 4]
b = [5, 6, 7, 8]

for ix, (i, ii) in enumerate(zip(a, b)):
    print('ix:', ix, 'i:', i, 'ii:', ii)
```

```
ix: 0 i: 1 ii: 5
ix: 1 i: 2 ii: 6
ix: 2 i: 3 ii: 7
ix: 3 i: 4 ii: 8
```

Comment: I resolved the issue. What I thought was a 1D array, was actually a matrix (the extraction of values from Titration_Datatable did it for each file, which there were multiple off). But since they were all duplicates, I defined a variable as np.unique, and removed the duplicates, giving me the same array you saw above, but now it was a 1D array.